# Помогите засетить поле у класса - наследника в спринг

Tags: java, spring

```
abstract class A {
    protected boolean bool = false;

    protected void setBool(Boolean bool){
        this.bool = bool;
    }
}

class B extends A {};
```

В конфигурационном файле пытаюсь для бина класса `B` установить значение переменной `bool`, однако получаю ошибку:

> bool is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: Попробуйте метод setBool сделать публичным в производном классе.

Comment: благодарю, ответ помог найти ошибку в написанном коде.

Comment: поле называлось по факту isBool, а сеттер setBool(), а правильный вариант setIsBool()

Answer (score 0):

поле называлось по факту isBool, а сеттер setBool(), а правильный вариант setIsBool() –